# Update query does not update row(s)

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I'm struggling with a very basic query. I can not see what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the first query I tried:

```
UPDATE `qrm_logs` SET `billable` = '0' AND `invoice_id` = NULL WHERE `id` = '842'
```

And the second:

```
UPDATE `qrm_logs` SET `billable` = 0 AND `invoice_id` IS NULL WHERE `id` = '842'
```

Column `billable` has type `enum`. Column `invoice_id` is an `int` type. Also, invoice_id can be nullable.

What causes this problem?

Comment: What about the id column in the where clause? is it text based? maybe it should be `id` = 842, withount the ' '.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be:

```
UPDATE `qrm_logs` SET `billable` = 0, `invoice_id` = NULL WHERE `id` = 842
```

note the comma instead of the AND.

Comment: Yes I noticed it 3 seconds ago. My bad... Thanks for pointing me the error. :)

Comment: you are welcome. Please mark the answer as solved then if you like

Comment: I will, as soon as it allows me to :)

Comment: I do not want to check wether the field is NULL, I want to update it to be NULL again.